# Load dependecy in bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

## My problem

I want to use `admin-lte` in my `laravel` app.
For this I want to require this js dependecy, I do this in my `bootstrap.js` (laravel-mix).

But the js isn't loaded, so for test I writed `console.log('bootstrap.js loaded')` in my bootstrap.js file, but the test isn't printed.

## How to help me

The boostrap.js is loaded by default? I have the same problem with `jquery`, it isn't loaded, this is not normal I think.

## My code

(resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js)

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

require('admin-lte')
console.log('bootstrap.js loaded')
```

(webpack.mix.js)

```
mix
  .disableNotifications()
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Not really enough info to go on here,  did you recompile?  are you loading the compiled script?

Comment: Have you update the resources with `npm run dev` or `yarn prod`?

Comment: Is your js being cached by the browser? Try versioning your assets in your webpack.mix.js file by adding `.version()`  `mix.disableNotifications().js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js').sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

I must require `bootstrap.js` in my `app.js`. And all work!